# AppleScript for change file names inside folders

Tags: macos, applescript

I need to write an AppleScript that can change my files names inside folder.Below is my scenario.

```
Folder1
   |
Folder2
   |
imageA.png,imageB.png
```

Now i need to write an AppleScript that can change name of imageA.png to A.png and imageB.png to B.png.

What should be my AppleScript for this? this is not my exact scenario but i am giving an example above so i can implement more from that.

I have tried below script and it is working well but i am getting error when filename is not exist, means it is not ignoring it.

```
tell application "Finder"

    set the name of file "iOs_142:About1.png" to "About1.png"
    set the name of file "iOs_142:FAQs.png" to "FAQs1.png"

end tell
```

Comment: How does this relate to iOS, and any particular reason for Applescript? There are certainly more efficient ways to rename files (or many alternatives).

Comment: No, it is not related to iOS. Reason behind Apple script is by once click i need changes in my required images.

Comment: Is the format you present in your example (`"iOs_142:About1.png" to "About1.png"`) always going to be the same?

Comment: Dos it means that you want a script which takes all files in a folder and rename each file from name xxxx:yyyy.ext to yyyy.ext . in other words change names of files by removing all characters before the ":" in each name. If so, please confirm that rule.

Comment: yes @CraigSmith its always same.

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on doing this with AppleScript, this should give a template to work forward with:

```
(* Taken from http://applescript.bratis-lover.net/library/string/#replaceString *)
on replaceString(theText, oldString, newString)
        local ASTID, theText, oldString, newString, lst
        set ASTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
        try
                considering case
                        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldString
                        set lst to every text item of theText
                        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to newString
                        set theText to lst as string
                end considering
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
                return theText
        on error eMsg number eNum
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASTID
                error "Can't replaceString: " & eMsg number eNum
        end try
end replaceString

tell application "Finder"
        set fs to files of folder POSIX file "/your/folder" as list
end tell
repeat with f in fs
        set n to replaceString(name of f, "to be replaced", "")
        tell application "System Events" to set name of f to n
end repeat
```